# EJB/JPA: Foreign Key Constraint violation when trying to persist entity in many-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, ejb, foreign-key-relationship

I have an EJB many-to-many (bi-directional) relation between classes (entity-classes) Person and Hobby. There are corresponding tables in the database, called PERSON and HOBBY, as well as a table PERSON_HOBBY for the many-to-many relationship.

As I will detail below,  the problem is that whenever I try to persist a person with hobbies, I run into a Foreign Key constraint violation. This is because the entityManager tries to save new rows into PERSON_HOBBY that contain references to a person-entity with ID=0, which doesn’t exist in the PERSON table. I’ll come back to that later, but first I’ll show the relevant parts of the entity classes.

First, here is entity class Person:

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    /* Note: I used to have CascadeType.PERSIST in the above line as well, but
      it caused "Detached object passed to persist" exceptions whenever I tried to 
      persist a person with hobbies. So I suppose I was right in deleting 
      CascadeType.PERSIST...? */
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_HOBBY",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName="id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="hobbyId", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private List<Hobby> hobbies = new ArrayList<Hobby>();

    public List<Hobby> getHobbies () {
        return hobbies;
    }     

    public void setHobbies (List<Hobby> hobbies) {
        this.hobbies = hobbies;
        for(Hobby h:hobbies) {  // this is to maintain bi-directionality
            h.addPerson(this);
        }
    }     
    // other getters and setters omitted here.
```

Then entity class Hobby:

```
@Entity
public class Hobby {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "hobbies", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Person> persons;

    public Hobby() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    // getter and setter for Description omitted here.

    public List<Person> getPersons () {
        return persons;
    }     

    public void setPersons (List<Person> persons) {
        this.persons = persons;
    }     

    public void addPerson (Person p) {
        this.persons.add(p);
    }
}
```

I also have a stateless session bean, that’s shown here as far as relevant to the issue:

```
        @Stateless
        @Default
        public class PersonRepositoryImpl implements PersonRepository {

            @PersistenceContext
            private EntityManager entityManager;

            @Override
            public Person create(Person p) {
               entityManager.persist(p);
               entityManager.flush();
               return p;
            }

            @Override
            public Person createPersonWithHobbies(Person p, List<Hobby>hobbyLijst) {
            p = create(p); // I've also tried simply: create(p);
            System.out.println("The newly assigned ID for the persisted 
            person is: " + p.getId()); 
            // That last line **always** prints the person-ID as being 0 !!!!
            p.setHobbies(hobbyLijst);
            entityManager.merge(p); // This should save/persist the person's hobby's!
            entityManager.flush();
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Now from my servlet, I've been trying in two different ways. First, I tried calling method `create(p)` on the above session bean. That is, after creating a new Person instance p, setting all its non-relational fields, AND calling setHobbies on it (with a non-zero list of Hobby objects taken from the database), I called:

```
personRepo.create(p);
```

But this resulted in the Foreign Key (FK) exception:

> INSERT on table 'PERSON_HOBBY' caused a violation of foreign key
>   constraint 'FK_EQAEPVYK583YDWLXC63YB3CXK' for key (0).  The statement
>   has been rolled back.”

The FK-constraint mentioned here is the one in PERSON_HOBBY referring to PERSON.

The second way I tried was to make the following call from the servlet:

```
personRepo.createPersonWithHobbies(p, hobbyLijst);
```

where, just like before, p is the new person object; and hobbyLijst is that person's list of hobbies. And this resulted in the exact same FK-exception as the earlier call to personRepo.create(p).

Importantly, the `println` statement within method `createPersonWithHobbies`, calling `getId()` on the newly persisted person-object, ALWAYS gives that object's ID as being 0. Which I suppose does explain the FK-exception, since there's no person entity/row in the PERSON table with an ID of 0, nor is there supposed to be one. But of course the `getId()` call should not output 0. Instead, it should output the newly generated ID of the newly persisted person entity. (And yes, it IS persisted correctly in the PERSON tabel, with a correctly generated ID>0. So the correct ID is there in the PERSON-table - it just seems to be invisible to the entityManager and/or the container.)

Thanks.

Comment: Could you try making your ids objects - Integer or Long? I think Hibernate might get confused by small int - it expects not-persisted entities to have a null id, while non-initialized int is 0.

Comment: @Deltharis Thanks. I tried your suggestion, but to no avail...
I woinder if the problem has something to do with Transactions - which I do not know much about at this stage, unfortunately.

Comment: and that Id starts as null, and after persist becomes 0? Really? What if you change something and try to merge it - which row in the database will it change?